# QML Loader tab Navigate exception

Tags: navigation, qml, loader

press 'Tab' key, first time, navigate successfully between the four controls. but since the second time, button1 can't focus.

**first time, navigation chain:**

checkbox1 -> checkbox2 -> button1 -> button2

**since the second time, navigation chain:**

checkbox1 -> checkbox2 -> button2

why?

////////////////////////////////
code:
// main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Column {
            CheckBox {
                id: checkbox1
                text: "checkbox1"
                focus: true
                KeyNavigation.tab: checkbox2
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: checkbox2
                text: "checkbox2"
                focus: true
                KeyNavigation.tab: loadItem
            }
            Loader {
                id: loadItem
                width: 100
                height: 40
                source: "OtherItem.qml"
                focus: true
                KeyNavigation.tab: checkbox1
            }
        }
    }
}

// OtherItem.qml

import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Row {
        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "button1"
            focus: true
            KeyNavigation.tab:  button2
            Keys.onReturnPressed: {
                console.log("button1 enter");
            }
        }
        Button {
            id: button2
            text: "button2"
            focus: true

            Keys.onReturnPressed: {
                console.log("button2 enter");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing all unnecessary `KeyNavigation.tab` and `focus: true` solves the problem.

Comment: There is this talk on *KeyNavigation* on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6qguJznMo4 that might give helpful insights in the correct use of `FocusScopes` and what the `property` `focus` actually means. It seems you have profound misconceptions especially about the latter ;-)

Comment: thanks all. Remove unnecessary focus, and FocusScopes as OtherItem.qml root object, solve the problem:

Comment: thanks all. Remove unnecessary focus, and FocusScopes as OtherItem.qml root object (FocusScope onActiveFocusChanged set button1 focus true), solve the problem